# Unit-testable C# FizzBuzz

Tags: c#, beginner, fizzbuzz

To support a demonstration I'm going to be doing, I need a short C# program that can be unit tested. I decided to make a FizzBuzz split into a few methods:

```
using System;
namespace FizzBuzz
{
    class FizzBuzzer
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            FizzBuzzer fizzBuzzer = new FizzBuzzer();
            int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
            fizzBuzzer.StartLoop(n);
        }

        public int StartLoop(int n)
        {
            int fizzBuzzes = 0;
            for(int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            {
                string output = getOutputForI(i);
                if(output == "FizzBuzz") {
                    fizzBuzzes++;
                }
                Console.WriteLine(output);
            }
            return fizzBuzzes;
        }

        public string getOutputForI(int i)
        {
            string s = "";
            if(i % 3 == 0)
            {
                s += "Fizz";
            }
            if(i % 5 == 0)
            {
                s += "Buzz";
            }
            if(s.Length == 0)
            {
                s = "" + i;
            }
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

I want people to focus on the point of my demonstration, and not on potential mistakes in my code. As someone new to C#, I can't evaluate my code very well. Are there any beginner mistakes that would distract pedantic C# experts?

I am of course open to any type feedback, I mainly just want people to not laugh at or get annoyed by my code.

---

Edit:

here are example unit tests

```
using Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UnitTesting;

namespace FizzBuzz.Tests
{
    [TestClass()]
    public class FizzBuzzerTests
    {
        [TestMethod()]
        public void StartLoopTest()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual(6, FizzBuzzer.StartLoop(100));
        }

        [TestMethod()]
        public void GetOutputFor0()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("FizzBuzz", FizzBuzzer.getOutputForI(0));
        }

        [TestMethod()]
        public void GetOutputFor4()
        {
            Assert.AreEqual("4", FizzBuzzer.getOutputForI(4));
        }
    }
}
```

and for context, here is the updated code (based on [Ron Beyer's answer](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/212569/37800)) that those tests are run against:

```
using System;
namespace FizzBuzz
{
    public static class FizzBuzzer
    {
        public static void Main() { }

        public static int CountFizzBuzzes(int max)
        {
            int fizzBuzzes = 0;
            for (int i = 1; i <= max; i++)
            {
                string result = FizzBuzz(i);
                if (result == "FizzBuzz")
                {
                    fizzBuzzes++;
                }

                Console.WriteLine(result);
            }
            return fizzBuzzes;
        }

        public static string FizzBuzz(int input)
        {
            string s = "";
            if (input % 3 == 0)
            {
                s += "Fizz";
            }
            if (input % 5 == 0)
            {
                s += "Buzz";
            }
            if (s.Length == 0)
            {
                s = "" + input;
            }
            return s;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Since your focus is on unit-testing then I think you should provide your tests too.

Comment: And about mistakes that can distract your audience... we don't give classes the same name as the enclosing namespace.

Comment: @t3chb0t I don't have unit tests, I just have code that _can be_ unit tested.

Comment: And thanks for catching the namespace; I did actually change that already, I just copied the wrong version of the code.

Comment: Well, nobody knows whether some code can be tested until you actually **try** to write tests ;-] This is a very deceiving feeling so I'd be really good if you wrote tests first.

Comment: I can already tell that **this is not testable** because of your console output... so...

Comment: @t3chb0t Understood. I'll see if I can prototype some unit tests soon.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Since it's a code-review site, I'll focus on issues you have with your code...

#### Having `Main` in your class

I would generally avoid this. I understand that this is probably a single-class demonstration project, but typically C# projects have a `Program` class that has `Main` inside of it, and I would stick with that. If you want to be able to unit-test `FizzBuzzer`, the `Main` function would not be unit-testable. As a result, your code-coverage of this class will be lower.

#### Inconsistent method names

You have a method properly cased as `StartLoop` and then you have an improper cased `getOutputForI`. Stick with the Microsoft recommendation of [Capitalization Rules for Methods](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/design-guidelines/capitalization-conventions) which should be Pascal Cased.

#### Method names and parameters that don't self-document

The name you give a method should identify to the caller what it does. `StartLoop` both starts and ends a loop, and runs the entire sequence. Ideally this would be named `Run` instead of `StartLoop`, but even then, what is it returning? Maybe `CountFizzBuzz` would be even better. Similarly, `getOutputForI` certainly gets the output for the method parameter `I`, but that really doesn't say what it does. Maybe consider renaming it to `FizzBuzz(int input)` instead.

Similarly the method parameters are not self documenting. What is `n` exactly in `StartLoop`? It would be more apparent if the method were something like `Run(int max)`. Which would also require a modification of your `for` loop because you would stop just shy of `max`. `i` is also not apparent of what it is (see a suggested version in the paragraph above).

#### Mixing UI with code

This makes your code unit-test unfriendly. You can't unit test the output to the console, so in order to unit test this you would need to pass a stream to the output:

```
public int CountFizzBuzz(int max, TextWriter output)
{
    int fizzBuzzes = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i <=max; i++)
    {
        string fizzBuzz = FizzBuzz(i);
        if (fizzBuzz == "FizzBuzz")
        {
            fizzBuzzes++;
        }
        output.WriteLine(fizzBuzz);
    }
    return fizzBuzzes;
}
```

Now this is unit-testable because you can create a `TextWriter` and pass in a value that can be `Assert`ed later.

### Inconsistent Brackets

You have two methods of writing brackets in your code, the "Microsoft" way, and the "Java" way. Again, I would stick with Microsoft practices here and use the one that has both brackets on their own lines.

#### Using an instance object for something that has no state

`FizzBuzzer` has no state, so why isn't everything `static`? There isn't a good reason to require a `new` each time you have to run the "Fizz Buzzer", take up space on the stack, etc. This class should be made `static`.

---

So with all my recommendations, here is what it would *possibly* turn out like:

```
public static class FizzBuzzer
{
    public static int CountFizzBuzzes(int max)
    {
        return CountFizzBuzzes(max, Console.Out);
    }

    public static int CountFizzBuzzes(int max, TextWriter output)
    {
        int fizzBuzzes = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i <= max; i++)
        {
            string result = FizzBuzz(i);

            if (result == "FizzBuzz")
                fizzBuzzes++;

            output.WriteLine(result);
        }
        return fizzBuzzes;
    }

    public static string FizzBuzz(int input)
    {
        string s = "";

        if (input % 3 == 0)
            s += "Fizz";

        if (input % 5 == 0)
            s += "Buzz";

        if (s.Length == 0)
            s = "" + input;

        return s;
    }
}
```

I still don't find this completely "ideal" as `CountFizzBuzzes` really does two things, counts them and outputs them to the stream. This really should be two separate methods for separation of concerns.

Just as a final note, your `Main` has an issue... Right now when you start the program it just stares at you with a blank window until you mash the right key(s).

```
public static void Main()
{
    FizzBuzzer fizzBuzzer = new FizzBuzzer();
    int n = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    fizzBuzzer.StartLoop(n);
}
```

What is to stop the user here from entering "My Name Is" instead of "42"? The `Convert.ToInt32` will throw an exception and the program will terminate. The user isn't even prompted for a number or any thing. At least prompt the user:

There are a multitude of questions on here about how to validate console input, so I'll leave that to you to research, but you should prompt the user *"Please Enter a Number:"* and if that isn't a number, tell them and ask again (and provide them a way to quit).

Comment: I wouldn't necessarily call not-using `{}` as _cleaned_.

Comment: @t3chb0t Maybe a poor choice of words, revised

Comment: Upvoted, very good answer - I would only point out that many *pedantic C# experts* you say making the conditional block scopes implicit isn't improving the code's maintainability.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon I'd be one of them! All good advice, except the bit about skipping `{}` for single-line ifs, with which I disagree vehemently.

Comment: @BittermanAndy FWIW I'm one of them as well. [Rubberduck](http://www.github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck) pull requests without these braces inevitably get the review comments and change suggestions accordingly ;-)